# Search prod definition for unremmed table reference

Tags: sql-server

So, I have been trying to search all of my stored procs for any reference to a specific view; and I can do this with:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%THEVIEW%'
```

Only problem is that I don't want to manually go thru all of them looking to see which ones are actually referencing the view, and which already have it commented out.  Does anybody have a good way of doing this?  My thought is there might be a software tool out there that can handle it (I'm assuming you can't do it via SQL)

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic as you are asking for a software recommendation. However, you might take a look at sql search by redgate. It is free and does database searches quite well. No matter what you choose you will have some level of manual effort.

Comment: You might also include another predicate in you where clause "AND NOT LIKE %--TheView%'. For this reason I would suggest you put your database objects in source control and not comment unused code. Remove it and check it in.

Comment: have you tried importing your db schema into a VS 2015/VS 2013 database project?

Comment: you could try below link which ouputs only entities depending on each other,i am sure you can filter out the view..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query to find all dependencies

This shows the objects depend on db.oMyView

```
SELECT
  coalesce(Referenced_server_name+'.','')+ --possible server name if cross-server
       coalesce(referenced_database_name+'.','')+ --possible database name if cross-database
       coalesce(referenced_schema_name+'.','')+ --likely schema name
       coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') + --very likely entity name
       coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referencing],
coalesce(object_schema_name(Referencing_ID)+'.','')+ --likely schema name
    object_name(Referencing_ID)+ --definite entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'') AS [referenced]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id =object_id('db.oMyView')
ORDER BY [referenced]
```

This shows the objects db.oMyView is depend on

```
SELECT
  coalesce(object_schema_name(Referencing_ID)+'.','')+ --likely schema name
    object_name(Referencing_ID)+ --definite entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'')
       AS [referencing],
  coalesce(Referenced_server_name+'.','')+ --possible server name if cross-server
       coalesce(referenced_database_name+'.','')+ --possible database name if cross-database
       coalesce(referenced_schema_name+'.','')+ --likely schema name
       coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') + --very likely entity name
       coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referenced]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referencing_id =object_id('db.oMyView')
ORDER BY [referenced]
```

Source: [Dependencies and References in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/dependencies-and-references-in-sql-server/)

Another reference: [Different Ways to Find SQL Server Object Dependencies](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/)

Answer (score 2):

sp_Depends also will do the trick..

```
create view vw_test
as
select 1 as 'b'

create proc usp_testvw
as
begin
select * from vw_test
end

create proc usp_testvw1
as
begin
select * from vw_test
end
```

now pass view which you want to check ..

```
sp_depends 'vw_test'
```

output:

```
name              type
dbo.usp_testvw    stored procedure
dbo.usp_testvw1   stored procedure
```

Comment: Perfect!  Didn't think there would be anything built in, but there it is!  Awesome!